# name of class of graphs: wheels with edges removed

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, terminology

If $G$ is a wheel graph then I know that a "broken wheel" refers to a graph obtained from removing "spokes" from $G$.  Is there a name for a graph that is obtained by removing edges from the outer ring of $G$?  That is, you are still breaking the wheel but you are restricting your removal to the outer ring of edges rather than the inner set of spokes?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no general (commonly used) term for the class of graphs described. Many special cases have names however. Wolfram recognizes star graph, 3,1-tadpole (or 3-pan or paw) graph, butterfly graph, cricket graph, dart graph and moth graph, all of which are representations of small-order wheel graphs with some or all outer edges removed.

Comment: But isn't a star graph always a tree?  If you remove some outer edges from a wheel you won't necessarily get a tree.

Comment: As the preceding comment points out, this "names" only the extremal case of removing *all* outer edges of a wheel graph, and in that it fails to fully address the Question.

Comment: I see. Some but not all of the outer edges have been removed, so it qualifies as neither a wheel nor a star graph. I don't know of a generalized term, though special cases might have names -- for example $W_5$ with two non-adjacent outer edges removed is a butterfly graph.